# am getting this error while playing a video in mp4

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pycharm, yolov8

WARNING  'source' is missing. Using 'source=C:\Users\ZAKARIYA\PycharmProjects\object-detection-yolo\venv311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\assets'.

image 1/2 C:\Users\ZAKARIYA\PycharmProjects\object-detection-yolo\venv311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\assets\bus.jpg: 640x480 4 persons, 1 bus, 1 stop sign, 141.7ms
image 2/2 C:\Users\ZAKARIYA\PycharmProjects\object-detection-yolo\venv311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\assets\zidane.jpg: 384x640 2 persons, 1 tie, 92.9ms
Speed: 4.0ms preprocess, 117.3ms inference, 5.6ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ZAKARIYA\PycharmProjects\object-detection-yolo\chapter 6- yolo webcam\yolo-webcam.py", line 43, in 
cv2.imshow("image",img)
File "C:\Users\ZAKARIYA\PycharmProjects\object-detection-yolo\venv311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\utils\patches.py", line 55, in imshow
_imshow(winname.encode('unicode_escape').decode(), mat)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Process finished with exit code 1

I tried to run but wasnt able to get any result also when a checking video in pycharm it shows following alert.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idfSc.png)

Comment: Is your filesize less than 1mb?